# BindingResult.rejectValue does not find value from ValidationMessages.properties

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations, validation

We're using spring with annotations, and our annotated fields get validated fine and error messages get displayed from ValidationMessages.properties, but for custom validation message from ValidationMessages.properties does not seem to be used.

Here's the example:

Validatior (also the form):

```
public void validateSpecial(BindingResult result) {

    if(password != null && !password.equals(passwordConfirm)){
       result.rejectValue("passwordConfirm", "emailform.passwordConfirm.passwordsDontMatch", new Object[]{}, "This message is in the code.");
```

...
        }

ValidationMessages.properties:

```
...
emailform.passwordConfirm.passwordsDontMatch = Passwords don't match
...
```

Controller:

```
...
    form.validateSpecial(result);
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "/path/to/input/page";
    }
...
```

The error that I get is "This message is in the code", not "Passwords don't match"

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem, thanks @Kartik

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>ValidationMessages</value>
            <value>ApplicationResources</value>            
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: So it seems like when it comes to annotated errors, Spring 3.0.X finds the messageSource w/o it explicitly defined in applicationContext, but when it comes to custom validator, spring needs messageSource defined in applicationContext

Comment: Sorry for not answering earlier. I just checked a stackoverflow until now. I am glad I was able to help in some way.